# Android WebView Focus

Tags: javascript, android, css, android-studio, android-webview

I make one Html file with javascript and CSS.

in javascript, I call function event handle and when I press down key then HTML li element can not focus but when I run in chrome there is focus on the element.

Javascript method

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
            var check = true;
            var active = document.querySelector(".hover0") || document.querySelector(".dropdownItemContainer li");

            document.addEventListener("keydown",handler);

            function handler(e){

                if(check){
                active.classList.add("hover0");
                check = false;
                console.log("Hello if");
                }else{
                console.log("Hello else");
                active.classList.remove("hover0");
                if (e.which == 40){
                    active = active.nextElementSibling || active;
                }else if (e.which == 38){
                    active = active.previousElementSibling || active;
                }else{
                    active = e.target;
                }
                active.classList.add("hover0");
                }
            }
        });
```

Web View settings

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Channel.html");
```

can anyone guide me

thank you